# AJAX ON RAILS - Can't update a bookmark symbol after delete, error 500

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So, the bookmark is actually getting destroyed. The thing is that the console throws an error 500 and the bookmark is not getting unselected. It does happen when i update the page, so it's actually getting destroyed but the AJAX request is not getting fulfilled by some reason. Here is my code:

**Bookmarks controller:**

```
  def destroy
@bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
@recommendation = Recommendation.find(@bookmark.recommendation_id)
if @bookmark.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to recommendation_path(@recommendation) }
    format.js  # <-- will render `app/views/reviews/create.js.erb`
  end
else
  flash[:notice] = "Couldn't delete bookmark"
  redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  return
end
```

end

Routes:

```
      resources :bookmarks, only: [:destroy]
  get "/recommendations", to: "recommendations#index"
  resources :recommendations, not: [:index] do
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :bookmarks, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

Destroy.js.erb:

```
function refreshForm2() {
  var els = document.querySelector("a[href='/bookmarks/<%=@bookmark.id%>']");
  els.setAttribute("data-method", "post");
  els.setAttribute("href", "/recommendations/<%= recommendation.id %>/bookmarks");
  els.querySelector("i").setAttribute("class", "far fa-bookmark fa-xs")
}

refreshForm2();
```

The error is:

> application-852f66c6902b94f224b15c5a88c6c45599d9e733ce132ce9a28ec6a092031d74.js:216
>   DELETE http://localhost:3000/bookmarks/27 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm really lost here. What am i doing wrong? The create works perfectly fine and updates the bookmark icon from unfilled to filled.

Comment: Can you change log level to debug. Check `config.log_level = :info` line within `config/environments/development.rb`. And provide a bit more details log output

Answer (score 0):

IT was actually a really silly mistake, thanks @Yurii for the logs tip. I'm really new to this and didn't even know how to check that, lol!